# How to remove JProfiler config from Websphere server?

Tags: jprofiler

Over the last few days I have been using JProfiler to profile a locally running Websphere 7 server (from within RAD8). I have used JProfiler's server integration feature to connect to the WAS instance.

I now want to remove the profiling from the WAS server instance - whenever I start up the server it shows up as "Profiling" - even though JProfiler is not running. How do you "unhook" JProfiler from the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integration wizard in JProfiler creates a backup of the `server.xml` config file in the same directory. You can use that backup to restore the previous state.

Alternatively, edit server.xml, look for "-agentpath:..." and remove that VM parameter.